# Python subprocess not executing when daemonized

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, daemon, popen

I try to execute a script inside a method where parent Class is daemonized.

autogamma.sh is a script that need ImageMagick to be installed (and use convert) that can be found here : http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autogamma/index.php

```
import os
import subprocess
import daemon

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myfunc()
    def myfunc(self):
        script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'autogamma.sh')
        cmd = ('/bin/sh %s -c average /tmp/c.jpg /tmp/d.jpg' % script).split(' ')
        ret = subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    process = MyClass()
    process.run()
```

Script executing correctly when launching the class MyClass only. I think there is a problem with env or something similar but cannot get it.

Problem is also happening with Rsync, mediainfo, ffprobe.
Using Python 2.7.3 with python-daemon 1.6 , tested on mac os, centos 5.5, ubuntu 12.04TLS

Comment: MyClass doesn't have a `run()` method, so I assume that's a typo?

Answer (score 2):

The script is pretty short, if you exclude the code for reading command line arguments,  comments and other color modes it is less than 75 lines. I would just convert it to Python.

Like the comments suggest, the best way would be to use one of the python wrappers for ImageMagick.

You could also call `convert` directly, though it's probably going to be painful. Here a small snippet of what that would look like:

```
import subprocess

def image_magick_version():
    output = subprocess.check_output("/usr/local/bin/convert -list configure", shell=True)

    for line in output.split('\n'):
        if line.startswith('LIB_VERSION_NUMBER'):           
            _, version = line.split(' ', 1)
            return tuple(int(i) for i in version.split(','))

im_version = image_magick_version()    
if im_version < (6,7,6,6) or im_version > (6,7,7,7) :
    cspace = "RGB"
else:
    cspace = "sRGB"

if im_version < (6,7,6,7) or im_version > (6,7,7,7):
    setcspace = "-set colorspace RGB"
else:
    setcspace = ""
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. And ditch using the shell in the process. The bottom of the linked page gives a short list of the commands used in the luminosity mode.

Comment: Using the [pgmagick](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgmagick/0.5.4) wrapper package may simplify the porting process.

Comment: Sadly it is not the only script that I use, so It would be really a pain to "translate" all scripts I use, the problem is also happening with Rsync, mediainfo and many other tools.

Answer (score 0):

When I suspect environment issues, I do one of two things:

1. Run the script in the foreground with "env - whatever-script".  This
   should clear out the environment, and send errors to your terminal's
   stderr.
2. Run the script normally, but with stdout and stderr redirected to a
   file in /tmp: whatever-script > /tmp/output 2>&1

These make tty-less scripts a bit less opaque.

Comment: cmd = ('/bin/sh %s -c average /tmp/c.jpg /tmp/d.jpg' % script)
ret = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, close_fds=False).communicate()
fd = open('/tmp/output', 'w').write(str(ret))


return ('','')

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. It was effectivly a path problem. After looking into the lib I found this usefull param:

```
    `working_directory`
        :Default: ``'/'``

        Full path of the working directory to which the process should
        change on daemon start.

        Since a filesystem cannot be unmounted if a process has its
        current working directory on that filesystem, this should either
        be left at default or set to a directory that is a sensible “home
        directory” for the daemon while it is running.
```

So I setted up the daemon like this:

```
with daemon.DaemonContext(working_directory='.'):
    process = MyClass()
    process.run()
```

And now I have the correct path and my script is properlly executed.